# 1600 MHz RAM, detected as 1333, XMP doesn't work

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, bios, cpufreq

I have an Asus M51AC-FR034S PC which has a M51AC motherboard that is in fact a rebranded H87M-PRO.

I have 2 RAM sticks (I don't know the exact word for that)

- A-Data MI64C1D1629Z1  8GB 1600 MHz Slot DIMM2
- Kingston HyperX KHX1600C10D3/8GX  8GB 1600 MHz Slot DIMM4

My problem is that the Kingston one is detected as 1333 MHz by the BIOS, so the first one too because the two must run at same frequency.
The bios looks like this : [My bios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvR9L.png)

When I click the XMP button, I have two items : XMP Profile #1, and "default" if I remember (not sure).
If I click the Profile #1, it says that "it will affect further DRAM settings" then the screen goes black for 1 or 2 seconds then I'm back to the BIOS, profile #1 is selected but it still shows 1333 MHz.
Also if I go in the advanced settings of the BIOS, in the RAM page, I see on my RAM stick that it has a XMP Profile with 1600 MHz.
So it seems that the BIOS sees that the RAM can run at 1600, but just doesn't want to apply the XMP profile.
Also I don't have the "Ai Tweaker" tab in the Advanced mode.

Is there a way to make the RAM run at the correct speed (1600) ?

Thanks

**The question is not "Can I use 1333 and 1600 together", both are 1600, the problem is that the second one is *detected* as 1333, but I want it to run at its normal speed, 1600**

**EDIT 1:** I can ask another question that will maybe solve my problem: How can I enable XMP and set the profile #1 on my H87M-PRO motherboard ? Because in the BIOS, I have (as shown in [My bios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvR9L.png)) a little "XMP" dropdown, when I click on it I have a small menu with "Profile #1" and if I click profile #1, the screen goes black for a few seconds and I get back in the BIOS but it's still at 1333 (even though Profile #1 is selected in the dropdown). When I select my second RAM stick in the RAM info page of the BIOS, I see that the detected frequency is 1333 but that the stick has a XMP Profile that runs at 1600.

**EDIT 2:** I tried all the 2 possibilities of placing the 2 RAM sticks in the 4 slots on my motherboard, it doesn't change anything, the Kingston is still detected as 1333 instead of 1600.

Comment: can't you just adjust ram speed manually?

Comment: No, my motherboard doesn't support overclocking