# Install H87M-PRO BIOS on M51AC (different model names, same motherboard)

Tags: motherboard, bios, overclocking, flashing

I currently own an Asus M51AC-FR034S that has an Asus M51AC motherboard.
When I updated the BIOS some time ago I noticed that the BIOS file name was

```
H87M-PRO-ASUS-M51AC-1002.CAP
```

Whereas H87M-PRO's one was

```
H87M-PRO-ASUS-2102.CAP
```

After some search, I noticed that the M51AC motherboard was in fact a rebranded H87M-PRO motherboard, without the 2 eSata ports (just search on Google Images, you'll see that the two are identical).

What I want is to install the latest H87M-PRO BIOS on my motherboard to access the new overclocking features, and to solve [my other question](https://superuser.com/questions/1006933/1600-mhz-ram-detected-as-1333-xmp-doesnt-work) (in the changelog of H87M-PRO BIOS 0713: "2.Fix XMP button issue") Ah. My XMP button doesn't work. This could solve that.
I tried to use Asus EZ Flash, it works with the M51AC BIOS but with the H87M-PRO one it shows an error "couldn't verify security key" or something like that.

Is there a way to force installing the BIOS, or to edit it to make the motherboard think it's a real M51AC BIOS?

Comment: Could you flash your BIOS with the latest H87M-PRO BIOS and did that work OK with you?

Comment: I tried, but both the ASUS Bios update software and the integrated 'ASUS EZ Flash' software said the BIOS image was corrupted. (I tried redownloading it)

Comment: Hm, I also tried BIOS upgrade yesterday. Same results.
I have updated BIOS but with M51AC version. That worked. But no XMP, no voltage control, no AI tweaker, no nothing.
Although, with the BIOS version M51AC BIOS 0901(not latest), XMP profile would change RAM frequency to 1600MHz, but computer would freeze after a few seconds. Maybe, you will have more luck with your RAM modules...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another way if you want to change the BIOS from the M51AC version to H87M-PRO version. Flash the first release BIOS for M51AC and then replace it with a BIOS for H87M-PRO, flash with the tool from AMI.

**Download:**

- The first release BIOS for M51AC, "[H87M-PRO-ASUS-M51AC-0118.CAP](https://mega.nz/file/aBQD1C4K#h4FV5rAODhWKruNpsAxZn4etcx_0X7n7vonzr1vwEmo)".
- The latest release BIOS for H87M-PRO, "[H87M-PRO-ASUS-2102.CAP](https://mega.nz/file/jAIBDQbB#-w-6XwAAt_JyJL61xvpxfS4N4MsVjj5-5cYoz2NJh6M)".
- The AfuWin64 tool for Aptio 4,"[Aptio_4_AMI_Firmware_Update_Utility.zip](https://mega.nz/folder/ucRXzKqB#810xeZ5_NVGcuhzbbf1nHg)"

Use AFUWINGUI.EXE to do the following steps.

**1.** Load H87M-PRO-ASUS-M51AC-0118.CAP.

**2.** Check "Do Not Check ROM ID"

**3.** Flash

Then when that is completed do:

**1.** Load H87M-PRO-ASUS-2102.CAP.

**2.** Check "Do Not Check ROM ID"

**3.** Check "Program All Blocks"
**Note:** *This will give you an error after

the tool have erased and flashed "Non Critical Block" part. But it

will clear up some leftovers from the previous BIOS. You might

accomplish the same thing by resetting the BIOS through the jumper
on the mainboard.*

**4.** Flash

**5. Reboot**

*(I also flashed the first release BIOS for the H87M-PRO mainboard and it was possible to flash to the latest version through EZ-Flash tool in BIOS options. But that was purely for testing if it would work to do that.)*

Comment: I'm gonna try that, although I am a bit scared to brick my motherboard. Are you 100% sure it'll work?

Comment: I have flashed the H87M-PRO BIOS 5-6 times, amongst the time when I tested the first release version to see it if would be possible to upgrade from that to the lates 2102 version. 

It have worked.

I would say that you face the same problems that you might with flashing in any other situation in that sense that it is as safe as when upgrading the M51AC BIOS.

Comment: On a side note. The two esata ports are actually there, ASUS have merely hidden them behind the backpanel on the M51AC chassi. I have not tested if they work though.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks. The three links were dead, but I managed to find mirrors.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible. I do that right now. All you need is a CH341A programmer from Aliexpress and Winbond 25Q128FVIQ chip for BIOS backup "just in case". After that M51AC motherboard is regular H87M-PRO with all OC options. Works fine and stable. Sorry for dig but I tried to find a solution for this problem almost a six months and no one knows.

Comment: If you want I can send you PM with short description, links and software.

Comment: @rvfvel It would be good if you would provide more description in case somebody finds out this answer and wants to try this method. How do you exactly use the programmer. Where do you download the BIOS file from. Please provide this information and edit your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

software: http://www38.zippyshare.com/v/EMzQ6TUL/file.html

I bought that stuff:

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Brand-U-Type-IC-Chip-Extractor-ROM-Extraction-Tool-DIP-Encapsulation-Stainless-Steel-Green-Clip-Extraction/32610238267.html?spm=2114.13010608.0.0.2N6BT7

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-shipping-2pcs-lot-W25Q128FVIQ-25Q128FVIQ-DIP8-laptop-chip-new-original/32688437735.html?spm=2114.13010608.0.0.2N6BT7   but 2 pieces it's too much

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/CH341A-24-25-Series-EEPROM-Flash-BIOS-USB-Programmer-with-Software-Driver/32535127770.html?spm=2114.13010608.0.0.2N6BT7

usefull links:

https://hardforum.com/threads/tools-to-flash-and-recover-bios-on-asus-p8xxx-boards-fd44editor-ftk.1726429/

links in polish because i'm from Poland, translate it in google translator

https://tosiek.pl/ch341-eeprom-and-spi-flash-programmer/

http://www.dobreprogramy.pl/OverFA/Programowanie-Bios-tanio-i-skutecznie,70460.html

my short description:

You need another computer with Windows to do that (I done this on my laptop with Windows 10)

First you should remove the original chip from motherboard and read it in CH341 program. When you save it on hard drive, file with BIOS backup, in FD44Editor you can read motherboard SN and Lan MAC adress and other stuff, copy it to clipboard and save in notepad. Then you have to write these informations onto new fresh bios file (save it as .bin file). And last step, write the overwritten file (with .bin) to new chip in CH341 program (open the bios file and press AUTO button or ERASE, BLANK, WRITE and VERIFY). And thats all, you have full H87M-PRO motherboard :)

Comment: I'd like to bring this wonderful answer back around to say that even in 2023, your advice worked. My Asus M51AC board would not even POST with an i7-4790 installed. I removed the BIOS chip from the board (it was socketed), backed up the contents using a T866II Plus programmer. I then found the FD44Editor as described and copied the relevant information from the backed up image. I pulled v2102 (H87M-PRO latest) and inserted the copied information to generate a new BIN, then flashed that to the chip in the programmer. Stuck the BIOS chip back in the board and it POSTED right away. Thank you!